# How can I limit the number of registrants to an event?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've set up a basic html/php submission form where people can register for our event, but need a way to replace the submission form webpage with one that reads something like "We have reached our registration limit" when we reach a certain number of submitted forms. Our database is MySQL (if that makes a difference) I've looked around on the web but people either say to count the entries by hand, or the ones that do have an automated system use CMS like drupal or joomla. Is it possible to setup an automated script that will do this?

Comment: I don't quite get your question regarding the automated script.

Is the submission form part of a CMS? Is it plain HTML - are you presenting the submission form form within a php script?

Comment: Plain HTML, no CMS. The submission form is in php inside an html div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row[0] > 50) echo 'We have reached our registration limit';
```

Comment: thanks! this might be a supremely basic question, but where should i past this on the page? As Ben said the queries are executed in sequential order, so should i paste this at the top?

Comment: You'd want to do it before the registration query occurs, so that you can halt the registration attempt and print the error message.

Comment: check has been marked! wish i could upvote it but i dont have enough rep

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert a record, count (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) all the previous registrations. After that all you need to do is a simple `if`.

Remember, DBs queries are executed in sequential order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nothing fancy, I'm not viewing your code, but you can make something like this:

your_file.php

```
<?

$count = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table "));

if ($count<10) {

   // your form code

}else{

  // your "full" message

}

?>
```

10 -> Max number of people to attend to that event!